# building cgal sln cannot be completed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, cmake, cgal

I have a problem while compiling CGAL 
I followed the steps here :
http://www.cse.msu.edu/~ytong/CGAL_installation.ppt

but when I reach at building CGAL  .sln step 
it show the following errors: 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU0oX.png)

**output**:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CGAL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/CGAL-4.9.1/src/CGAL/CMakeLists.txt
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\dev\CGAL-4.9.1\build\src\CGAL\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  all_files.cpp
1>     Creating library C:/dev/CGAL-4.9.1/build/lib/Debug/CGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.9.1.lib and object C:/dev/CGAL-4.9.1/build/lib/Debug/CGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.9.1.exp
1>all_files.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (__imp_?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
1>all_files.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (__imp_?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'errno_ecat''(void)" (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\dev\CGAL-4.9.1\build\bin\Debug\CGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.9.1.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is Boost installed and found by CMake? What version of Boost and CMake?

Comment: yes,Boost is installed boost_1_59_0 , cmake 3.7.1

Answer (score 1):

We are currently at CGAL 4.12 so please upgrade and follow official installation instructions.

Comment: is it compatible with visual studio 2013?